# android ndk, import external static library file

Tags: android, android-ndk

How can I use '.a' static library built with NDK.
Where do I attach header files( include file ) to call a function.

My Android studio version is 2.23.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the formal documentation, if you haven't tried it already. Here is the general page showing how to add a prebuilt library: [Using Prebuilt Libraries](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html)